# Untimely new answer alerts

Tags: bug, user-interface, live-refresh

Just this moment I had the following odd situation:

I posted an answer and was waiting for it to be submitted (say more than 10s) - with still the "cancel" option present. While waiting, I was alerted of a new answer - still I saw that my answer has not been submitted. So I was tempted to look at that answer first. Fortunately didn't.

As it turned out, the answer was mine. So for some time I was in an inconsistent state.

The only particularly odd configuration is my mobile connection, with occasional long lags, using the desktop version.

Comment: Weird stuff happens if your internet connection sucks. Don't worry about it.

Comment: I've noticed a similar race condition when editing. After it displays the updated question, it says "The question has been edited", but it's referring to my edit.